# how to let jQuery plugin function return intrinsic value

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, this, return-value

I am using the following pattern to write a jquery plugin, and I want the `bar` function to return intrinsic value, but it seems always to return `$(this)` instead.
Anything wrong with the code?

```
(function($){

    var Foo = function(elements, options){
    ... ...
    }


    Foo.prototype = {

        constructor: Foo,

        bar: function(){
            var value = ...        
            // do something here
            return value;
        },

    }

    $.fn.foo = function (option, kwargs){  
        return this.each(function(){ 
            var $this = $(this),
                data = $this.data('foo'),
                options = typeof option == 'object' && option

            if (!data) $this.data('foo', (data = new Foo(this, options)))
            if (typeof option == 'string') return data[option](kwargs)
        })            
    }


})(jQuery)
```

Comment: Intrinsic: *"Innate, inherent, inseparable from the thing itself, essential."*... I don't get it

Comment: @Codemonkey just values, like int, string. Here I want it to return string

Comment: OK thanks for the deliberation

Comment: What if `this` has two elements in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, the code is correct. The problem is that it's currently set up to always return a jQuery selector (the return value of `this.each`). To return the result of your function instead, you could modify your function for `$.fn.foo` like so:

```
$.fn.foo = function (option, kwargs){  
    var retval = null;

    this.each(function(){ 
        var $this = $(this),
            data = $this.data('foo'),
            options = typeof option == 'object' && option

        if (!data) $this.data('foo', (data = new Foo(this, options)))
        if (typeof option == 'string') {
          retval = data[option](kwargs);
        }
    })

    if (!retval) {
      retval = this;
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the outer function, you wrote `return`this.each(...);`.

`this.each` always returns the jQuery object you call it on (for chaining); it ignores the return value of the callback you pass it.

If you want to return a value from the callback, put that value in a variable, then return the variable after calling `each`.  (this will work because `each` is not asynchronous).
You will need to figure out what to do if your method is called on a jQuery object with two elements; you may want get rid of the `each` call entirely.

Comment: So how should I make it return string or int instead of jQuery object?

Comment: @Jensen: By `return`ing something other than `.each` from your method.  See the second half of my answer.